# Where should i add the json code when wanting to create a free shipping bar in my cart drawer (Flex - out of the sandbox)

Tags: json, shopify, liquid

I have tried to find the right section to implement the json code, however, i simply haven't been succesful in finding the right .liquid file.
Somehow i cant find any .liquid files from the theme settings module (theme settings = Theme customizer --> theme settings)
Where should i add the json code when wanting to create a free shipping bar in my cart drawer (Flex - out of the sandbox)

Regards
Alex

Comment: What you try and some code snapshots help someone to suggest to you what you may try, without any information. no body able to make any help

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you will need to add this to your `cart-template.liquid` file.